# How to fill passwordbox and click submit with webview on UWP app

Tags: javascript, c#, html, uwp

Here is html page that I want to fill a form

```html
<form action="validate.asp" method="post">
  <input type="TEXT" name="f_uid" size="20" value=""/><br />
  <input type="PASSWORD" name="f_pwd" size="20"/><br />
  <input name="BUILDKEY" type="HIDDEN" value="42779"><br/>
  <input type="SUBMIT" value="SubmitTest">
</form>
```

And here is a code that I'm use on UWP app

```
string[] cmds = new string[] { $"document.getElementsByName(\"f_uid\")[0].value = testuser",
        $"document.getElementsByName(\"f_pwd\")[0].value = testpass",
        "document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();"};
await test.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", cmds);
```

It's work only on Username field but Password and submit button not click

And I'm tried changing click(); to submit(); but that was not work either..

So is there an alternative? like call validate.asp instead? or something else..

Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code

```
string cmds = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByName('f_uid')[0].value = 'testuser';
                              document.getElementsByName('f_pwd')[0].value = 'testpass';
                              document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();"};
await test.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { cmds });
```

---

Coming to

> am I doing it wrong?

I think you have to end each line with `;` Like the code shown below

```
string[] cmds = new string[] { @"document.getElementsByName('f_uid')[0].value = testuser;",
                               @"document.getElementsByName('f_pwd')[0].value = testpass;",
                               @"document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();"};
await test.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", cmds);
```

---

Here is a sample app to LogIn to StackOverflow: [StackOverFlow LogIn](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/StackOverFlow-LogIn)

Comment: funny, the problem is I just forget ;
typical.. 

Comment: thank you, but one problem... there is no submit button
they all input
but I'm manage fix it by this.
    string[] cmd3 = new string[] { @"document.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].click();" };
and now it's work!